# Remove Cookies from JS or CSS files

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, cookies

Bizarrely my javascript and css files have cookies (says Firebug). I use Zend Framework and I think it has to do with it. Could I change the .htaccess that CSS or JS files don't link to the ZF or is there another solution?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

In my bootstrap file I start the session automaticly,
could I detect there really existing files and deactive sessions/cookies?

Comment: Maybe this is a question for serverfault.com?

Answer (score 4):

Cookies aren't in js or CSS files: they are transferred over the HTTP headers.

You can minimize the space they take but if you rely on them, you can't really get rid of them.  You can always "move" the static files someplace else so you don't incur the "cost" of the additional headers e.g. cookies.  Other place being --> other domain where you suppress cookies altogether.

Comment: OP: only uour browser has cookies, not the individual files. however, cookies are transferred in the HTTP headers if they exist during the transfer of individual files

Comment: Yes, that's right, the HTTP header send the cookie, I have dedicated myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can **place your CSS and JavaScript files and your Images on a "static" webserver** or subdomain which does not accept cookies. There are two very good explanations out there:

- Article about [Serve Static Content](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/page-speed/docs/request.html#ServeFromCookielessDomain) by Google
- Article about [Cookie free Domain](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free) by Yahoo!

Comment: That is it what I mean. But could I set "no cookie sending/accepting" for all files in a separated folder (with a .htaccess in it)?

Comment: No you can not. Cookies are sent by the browser and if he has a cookie set by a site he will send a cookie with every request to the domain that set the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are set per domain, so the browser will send them along with every request it makes to that domain, regardless what type of resource it is requesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove useless cookies. Example on htaccess with apache :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$"> 
     Header unset Cookie 
     Header unset Set-Cookie 
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems there is a way :

```
Header unset Set-Cookie
```

Comment: Cookie will still be sent in request header if you use the same domain to serve assets as main content. That would prevents usually a CDN from caching a file. Using a second domain on which no cookie is set will make sure that your server will not respond with a cookie, and doing so, CDN and browser will be able to cache what's served.